# Why does loop tiling decrease running time of a function?

Tags: c, loops, transpose

I am working with a function that transposes a matrix. My question is why does loop tiling decrease the running time especially of that function?

I understand why it works when, for example, multiplying matrices as the elements are being reused, but why is tiling faster when we still only access each element once in the transpose function?

Comment: Caching perhaps?

Comment: @lucidbrot yes, thank you! Haven't seen that post

Comment: Maybe you should [edit] and post both versions of your code. Also look at the generated assembly code which might give you a hint.